# JAVA - .sh file executing from terminal but not via JAVA code

Tags: java, shell, sh

I have a JAVA code to create and execute .sh file. The problem is - .sh file is getting created but not getting executed via the JAVA code. When run manually from terminal or cronjob, it gets executed. The big problem is - same code is working fine on all DEV servers but not on client PROD environment with CentOS 6.8. It is also working fine on Client UAT environment with CentOS 6.5.

The code creates executable sh file on the application server and executes it. sh file contained commands sqlldr and sqlplus to upload data via batch upload mechanism. When executed successfully, a log file is created with output of execution. Any errors like are written in the log file. When sh file is not executed, log file is also not created. When executed manually from terminal, sh file is executed and log file is also created. Below are the contents of sh file

```
sqlldr user/pass@db CONTROL=CTL_1000004453.ctl silent=all
echo -e "UPDATE QT_BATCH_UPLOAD SET UPLOAD_STATUS = 20 WHERE UPLOAD_ID = 1000004453;
commit;
exit;
" > SET_STATUS_1000004453.SQL
sqlplus user/pass@db @SET_STATUS_1000004453.SQL
```

No error is getting obtained in application and server logs. Application is running on Weblogic server. I have checked and eradicated all permission related issues.

Please help if anyone has encountered such non-replicating issue ever.

Below is the code.

```
        try
        {

          Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
          Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "cd " + path + " ;chmod a+x " + exeFile + "; sh " + exeFile + ";" });

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

          FileOutputStream file3 = new FileOutputStream(path + "CONSOLE_" + uploadID + ".LOG");
          String line; while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { String line;
            System.out.println(line);
            file3.write((line + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes());
            file3.flush();
          }
          file3.close();

        }
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, when you do get it to work, don't do it like this. You have the bash equivalent of a SQL injection vulnerability here (e.g. if exeFile is `/; rm -rf /`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'll look into that, but could you please help me get this working first?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. No change in code was required. Actually the app server (Weblogic) was being run via console. I did some R&D and asked the client to run it via putty/terminal, post which, the code ran fine.

I would still look for solutions to get the same working when weblogic runs via console.